# index.php is only displaying current month's posts?

Tags: posts, loop

The blog portion of my WordPress site (a corporate website) utilizes index.php as the default blog page. However, while the page properly shows the PAGING for the other 40+ pages of blog posts, the front page of the blog (again, index.php) is only showing the current month's posts in the loop before displaying the paging nav footer. Is this a default WordPress function, and if so, how would I override it? I hadn't even noticed it until today, when we have a single post for December, and that's all that shows until you go to page 2, etc.

Also, before we even had a post for December, this page was blank except for the paging nav footer, and again, once you went past page 1, all posts were showing correctly in chronological order.

So in short, why does index.php only show the current month's posts, and if none exist from the current month, return nothing from the loop until page 2, etc.?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? If yes - have you tried switching to one of the default themes to see if it might me caused by the theme?

Comment: My theme is extremely customized, but based on Bones.  Funny thing is, on my local environment, it's working correctly, so I assume it can't be the theme files (since those are identical locally and remotely).  However, the database has changed since it's been live on the remote server, as have some of the settings, categories and so on that I've modified via the admin on the live server.  Plugins are identical, as is the Wordpress version (4.0.1).  Still a mystery.  Thanks for the quick response/tip, I'll keep sleuthing.

Comment: But yes, it's the same behavior when I changed the theme on the remote server.  Grr!

Comment: And this is the loop: 
    `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  <?php if ( in_category('1173') ): //just blog posts ?>  blah blah blah  <?php endif; ?>  <?php endwhile; ?>`